# Powershell scripts from Install4j

Tags: scripting, installation, install4j

I have powershell scripts in file (.ps1), How can I run it from Install4j during the installation?

If I'm choosing "Run Script" control, What should I need to write inside?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather use a "Run executable" action for that purpose. You can then call the excutable

```
${installer:sys.system32Dir}\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

with the command as the argument.